# Get a reference to the last seen VC before backgrounding in scene delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `rootViewController` as `UITableViewController`, where when a cell gets tapped it presents a modal VC. In those VC's I'm doing animations with `UIViewPropertyAnimator` and the issue is when the app gets sent to the background while currently displaying that VC because the animators are not stopped correctly and my `viewWillDissapear` is not called where I'm stopping the animators.

- The question would be how to get a reference to a modal VC in my
  `sceneDidEnterBackground` so that I can stop the animators correctly?

If I wanted to get a reference to my rootVC its easy enough like `window.rootViewController` but what about a modal VC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `modal VC` IS the **TOPMOST** screen, and I think it should be the topmost screen you want to get reference from.

And if so, there are lots of references out there for that. But here's the whole function that I used the last time I needed it.

```
var windowScene: UIScene? = {
    let windowScene = UIApplication.shared
    .connectedScenes
    .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
    .first
    return windowScene
}()

var windowRootController: UIViewController? {
    if let window = windowScene as? UIWindowScene {
        return window.windows.last?.rootViewController
    }

    return UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.rootViewController
}

/// Category for any controller.
extension UIViewController {
    /// Class function to get the current or top most screen.
    class func current(controller: UIViewController? = windowRootController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let controller = controller else { return nil }

        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return current(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return current(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller.presentedViewController {
            return current(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

---

So basically, just call it like `let modalVC = UIViewController.current()`.

Play with this piece of codes, like I'm pretty sure you won't need the `windowScene` and `windowRootViewController`, not 100% sure though. Try it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this `controller.presentedViewController` property seems to be what I was looking for